# Using boot-clj dependency from local

Tags: clojure, boot-clj

I'm experimenting with [`boot-new`](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot-new). I'm making some changes to the code and need to test with `boot -d`. How can I test any boot dependency without having it available in clojars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test the changes for the boot dependency libs (the one that we supply in `-d`), we can make changes to those lib and run `boot build`. This add the updated jar to our local maven repo and it will be used when we refer it via `boot -d`.